# Periodic tns-12531: TNS: Cannot allocate memory

Tags: oracle, database-administration

I have a problem that's been plaguing me about a year now.  I have Oracle 12.1.x.x installed on my machine.  After a day or two the listener stops responding and the listener.log contains a bunch of `TNS-12531` messages.  If I reboot, the problem goes away and I'm fine for another day or two.  I'm lazy and I hate rebooting, so I decided to finally track this down, but I'm having no luck.  Since the alternative is to do work that I really don't want to do, I'm going to spend all my time researching this.

Some notes:

- Windows 10 Pro
- 64-Bit
- 32 GB RAM
- Generally, about 20GB free when the error occurs
- I have several databases and it doesn't matter which DB is running
- Restarting the DB doesn't help
- Restarting the listener doesn't help
- Only rebooting clears the problem
- When I set `TRACE_LEVEL_LISTENER = 16`, I don't get much more info.  Trace files are not written to
- I can connect to the DB if I bypass the listener (ie, set `ORACLE_SID=xxx` and connect without a DB identifier)
- All other network interactions seem to work fine after the listener stops
- lsnrctl status hangs and adds another `TNS-12531` to the listener.log
- I have roughly the same config at home and this does not happen

Below is an example of a `listener.log` file:

```
Fri Jul 28 14:21:47 2017
System parameter file is D:\app\user\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\listener.ora
Log messages written to D:\app\user\diag\tnslsnr\LJ-Quad\listener\alert\log.xml
Trace information written to D:\app\user\diag\tnslsnr\LJ-Quad\listener\trace\ora_24288_14976.trc
Trace level is currently 16

Started with pid=24288
Listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=LJ-Quad)(PORT=1521)))
Listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(PIPENAME=\\.\pipe\EXTPROC1521ipc)))
Listener completed notification to CRS on start

TIMESTAMP * CONNECT DATA [* PROTOCOL INFO] * EVENT [* SID] * RETURN CODE
28-JUL-2017 14:22:06 * 12531
TNS-12531: TNS:cannot allocate memory
28-JUL-2017 14:22:47 * 12531
TNS-12531: TNS:cannot allocate memory
28-JUL-2017 14:26:24 * 12531
TNS-12531: TNS:cannot allocate memory
```

Thanks a bunch for any help you can provide!

Comment: we are getting error on Linux system but getting same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Issue 1

This error can occur approximately after 2048 connections have been made via the listener when running on a non-English Windows installation.

#### Fix for Issue 1

Create a Windows User Group named **Administrators** on the computer where the listener.exe resides. This can fix the issue of the listener dying.

***Reference:*** I'll post the link for the first issue as soon as I find it again

---

### Issue 2

This error can also occur on Windows 64-Bit systems where the **Desktop Application Heap** is too small.

#### Fix for Issue 2

> Try to Increase the Desktop Application Heap Registry in windows its located in
>
> ```
> HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\SubSystems\Windows
> ```
>
> Just as note don't add this Value by yourself, you have to depend on document.

Basically search for the registry entry and alter the third value for the key `SharedSection=1024,20480,1024`. This is a trial and error approach, but seems to improve listener's stability and memory issues.

***Reference:*** [TNS:cannot allocate memory - is there limit to the num databases on one box](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2468947) (Oracle Developer Community)

Answer (score 0):

$ lsnrctl

LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 12.2.0.1.0 - Production on 13-NOV-2023 17:07:13

Copyright (c) 1991, 2016, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Welcome to LSNRCTL, type "help" for information.

LSNRCTL> **set TRACE_LEVEL_LISTENER = 16**

NL-00853: undefined set command "TRACE_LEVEL_LISTENER".  Try "help set"

LSNRCTL> set trc_level 16

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=192.168.56.62)(PORT=1521)))

TNS-12541: TNS:no listener

TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error

TNS-00511: No listener

Linux Error: 111: Connection refused

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))

TNS-12541: TNS:no listener

TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
TNS-00511: No listener

Linux Error: 2: No such file or directory